# show uploaded files using servlet and jsp

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am making a simple dynamic web application.

In this i had uploaded files on server tomcat at local host using common files upload in my servlet.

I want to show them on jsp page as icons(eg. pdf,doc,ppt) which gets downloaded when we click on icons.

How can i do this?

Here is my jsp page where i want to show them:

```
        `<%@ page language="java" 
        contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1256"
        pageEncoding="windows-1256"
        import="loginpkg.UserBean"
         %>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
         <html>
         <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" 
         content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
         <title>   User Logged Successfully   </title>
         </head>
          <body>
          <center>
          <% 
          UserBean currentUser = new UserBean();
          if (session != null) {
            currentUser = (UserBean) 
           session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser");
          }
                %>
        Welcome <%= currentUser.getFirstName() + " " + 
        currentUser.getLastName() %>
        upload your files here  
                    <form action="FileUpload" method="post" 
                    enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="file" >
                    <input type="submit" value="upload">
                     </form>

                   your uploaded files are:-

              **iwant to show the files here as icons,which gets downloaded 
               on clicking them**
               </center>
                 </body>
                </html>`
```

Comment: Store the relative path in Database and show it .

Comment: @SumeshTG  i had made a table that has file name n directory where it is uploaded, but the main thing is how i can show them as icons with a download link on those icons

Comment: @SumeshTG 
help me on this, how to show them on web page

Comment: You should identify the file type by examining the extensions and show icons based on the extensions.You need to harcode  the extensions like .doc,.docx...etc

Comment: You need to apply some logic to identify the file extensions.

Comment: @SumeshTG ok thanks i will try to do this

Comment: Welcome @Deepakpannu